# object reference is not set to an instance of an object after clickonce deployment?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, clickonce

We got an error when try to publish the application using clickonce i.e.,

> "obj\UAT\CSymplBridge.exe.config;obj\UAT\CSymplBridge.exe.config" is an invalid value for the "ConfigFile" parameter of the "GenerateApplicationManifest" task. Multiple items cannot be passed into a parameter of type "Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem".

So, in research we fix the issue by replacing

```
<AppConfigWithTargetPath Remove="App.config" />
```

with

```
<AppConfigWithTargetPath Remove="@(AppConfigWithTargetPath)" />
```

in the `.csproj` file.

Then we are able to publish the application. After installing the application, I get the error

> Object reference is not set to an instance of an object

at the line

```
string configname = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SolutionConfiguration"];
```